# Почему высвечивается ошибка в ListView?

Tags: vbscript, visual-studio

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему высвечивается ошибка:

> Ошибка - ссылка на член, не являющийся общим, должна быть ссылкой на объект.

Код:

```
Private Sub FoldEx()
    Dim itim As ListViewItem
    With ListView1.ListViewItemCollection.Clear
        itim = .Add(, , "Рисунки", 1)
        itim = .Add(, , "Документы", 1)
        itim = .Add(, , "Музыка", 1)
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что надо убрать .Clear

Answer (score 1):

Из MSDN:

> В коде имеется ссылка на член, не являющийся общим, но отсутствует ссылка на объект. Для определения имени члена, не являющегося общим, нельзя использовать имя класса. Необходимо сначала объявить экземпляр как объектную переменную, а затем ссылаться на него, используя имя переменной.

Надо в таком духе:

```
Dim listView As New ListView()
Dim item As New ListViewItem("item", 0)

item.SubItems.Add("1")
item.SubItems.Add("2")
item.SubItems.Add("3")

listView.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {item})
```